# xUnit Test Add Model to List Failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, xunit, nancy

I'm using xUnit to test my project. I have a test that checks if a `user` has been added the a `list` of `users` shown below:

```
private readonly IJsonService _jsonService;
private readonly IUserService _userService;

[Fact]
    public void Add_User_To_User_List()
    {
        //Given
        _userService = new UserService(_jsonService, _guidService);
        _jsonService = Substitute.For<IJsonService>();

        var _fakeUserJsonFile = "Users.json";
        var _fakeNewUser = new User()
        {
            ID = new Guid(),
            FirstName = "Denis",
            LastName = "Menis"
        };

        var _fakeUserList = new List<User>
        {
            new User()
                {
                    ID = new Guid(),
                    FirstName = "Paddy",
                    LastName = "Halle"
                },
            new User()
                {
                    ID = new Guid(),
                    FirstName = "Job",
                    LastName = "Blogs"
                }
        };

        var _fakeUpdatedUserList = new List<User>
        {
            new User()
                {
                    ID = new Guid(),
                    FirstName = "Paddy",
                    LastName = "Halle"
                },
            new User()
                {
                    ID = new Guid(),
                    FirstName = "Job",
                    LastName = "Blogs"
                },
            new User()
                {
                    ID = new Guid(),
                    FirstName = "Denis",
                    LastName = "Menis"
                }
        };

        _jsonService.DeserializeObject<User>(_fakeUserJsonFile).Returns(_fakeUserList);
        _jsonService.SerializeObject(_fakeUserJsonFile, _fakeUpdatedUserList).Returns(true);

        //When
        var result = _userService.AddUser(_fakeNewUser);

        //Then
        Assert.Contains(_fakeNewUser, _fakeUpdatedUserList);
    }
```

Now I know that the code works because I wrote it first but when I run my test it fails! Below is my code to add the user to the user list:

```
public bool AddUser(User user)
    {
        var userList = GetUsers();

        user.ID = _guidService.NewGuid();

        userList.Add(user);

        var serializeObject = _jsonService.SerializeObject(_fileName, userList);

        return serializeObject;
    }
```

GetUser Method:

```
public List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return _jsonService.DeserializeObject<User>(_fileName).ToList();
    }
```

Deserialise Method:

```
private readonly IFileSystem _file;
    private readonly HttpContextBase _httpContext;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public JsonService(IFileSystem file, HttpContextBase httpContext, ILogger logger)
    {
        _file = file;
        _httpContext = httpContext;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> DeserializeObject<T>(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var relativeFileName = _httpContext.Server.MapPath(fileName);
            var readFile = _file.ReadAllText(relativeFileName);
            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(readFile);
            return list;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogException(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

FileSystem class:

```
public class FileSystem : IFileSystem
{
    public void WriteAllText(string path, string contents)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, contents);
    }

    public string ReadAllText(string path)
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(path);
    }
}
```

When I run my test, `var serializeObject = _jsonService.SerializeObject(_fileName, userList);` from the `AddUser` method returns false every time.

I think it's doing this because even though it's the same data as the expected result, in memory it's a different reference to the same data.

Can anyone help me with this I want it to return the same referenced data. If I'm not being very clear I can elaborate more. Thanks

Comment: Can you show some of the setup code? In particular, the code that links `_fileName` to `_fakeUserJsonFile`, and `userList` to `_fakeUpdatedUserList`?

Comment: @Lilshieste I've updated the code to show the data

Comment: Thanks! One more question: what mocking framework are you using? NSubstitute? (i.e., what is the type of `_jsonService`?)

Comment: I'm using NSubstitute yes. I'll update the `_jsonService` code, it's just a class that reads and writes to a generic json file

Comment: Can't you just use _fakeUserList and drop _fakeUpdatedUserList all together?

Comment: no it still fails to serialise the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right that the problem is rooted in the fact that `_fakeUserList` and `_fakeUpdatedUserList` reference two completely different objects. You've configured `_jsonService.SerializeObject` to return `true` when it is passed a reference to `_fakeUpdatedUserList` - but you're actually passing a reference to (a modified) `_fakeUserList`.

Basically, `_fakeUpdatedUserList` is completely unnecessary. You can focus on `_fakeUserList`, since that is the object that gets provided to the SUT (via `DeserializeObject<User>`, presumably).

For example:

```
[Fact]
public void Add_User_To_User_List()
{
    //Given
    _userService = new UserService(_jsonService, _guidService);
    _jsonService = Substitute.For<IJsonService>();

    var _fakeUserJsonFile = "Users.json";
    var _fakeNewUser = new User()
    {
        ID = new Guid(),
        FirstName = "Denis",
        LastName = "Menis"
    };

    var _fakeUserList = new List<User>
    {
        new User()
            {
                ID = new Guid(),
                FirstName = "Paddy",
                LastName = "Halle"
            },
        new User()
            {
                ID = new Guid(),
                FirstName = "Job",
                LastName = "Blogs"
            }
    };

    _jsonService.DeserializeObject<User>(_fakeUserJsonFile).Returns(_fakeUserList);
    _jsonService.SerializeObject(_fakeUserJsonFile, _fakeUserList).Returns(true); // Match the original _fakeUserList, since that is what gets passed in by the implementation

    //When
    var result = _userService.AddUser(_fakeNewUser);

    //Then
    Assert.Contains(_fakeNewUser, _fakeUserList); // Verify that the provided _fakeUserList has been modified
}
```

On a side note: you can actually remove a lot of the details from this test, as they're irrelevant to the functionality that is being tested. For example, `_fakeUserList` can initially be empty - it doesn't have to contain any dummy values. And you can use the default values for `_fakeNewUser` (i.e., without specifying `FirstName` etc.), as they're not referenced at all in this test.

**Edit:** Thanks for posting the additional code (for `GetUsers`, etc.). This code shows that you're invoking `ToList()` on the `IEnumerable<User>` that is returned by `DeserializeObject<User>`. This is why your mock object is not behaving as you expect: the list returned by `ToList()` is a completely separate list from `_fakeUserList`.

Additionally, I don't see anywhere in your test where `_fakeUserJsonFile` is being injected into the SUT. So the `_fileName` in `AddUser` might not be what you're expecting, as well.

To get around this, you either need to modify your design (e.g., to not call `ToList`), or modify the expected behavior in your test. While you may want to consider the possibility of the former, the latter might be easier.

For example:

```
    // Match any filename (unless you have a way of getting _fakeUserJsonFile into the SUT)
    // Match any list, as long as it contains the new user
    _jsonService.SerializeObject(Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Is<List<User>>(list => list.Contains(_fakeNewUser))).Returns(true);

    //When
    var result = _userService.AddUser(_fakeNewUser);

    //Then
    Assert.IsTrue(result); // Only returns true if the mock object is invoked as expected

    // There is no way to verify the following assertion, because the test has no way of accessing the "updated" list
    //Assert.Contains(_fakeNewUser, _fakeUserList);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, it still fails to serialise the user even when I just use the above code, that's why I think it's getting the same variables (I.E `_fakeUserJsonFile` & `_fakeUserList`) as different references in memeory if that makes sense

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure that `_fileName` references the same object as `_fakeUserJsonFile`. You also need to make sure that `GetUsers` returns the list returned by `DeserializeObject<User>` (i.e., not a copy of it). If you post the code for `GetUsers` (and the code that sets `_fileName`) we can verify whether or not the references are the same.

Comment: I've added the getuser method and the deserialise method

Comment: The problem is in the `DeserializeObject` method: when you call `ToList()`, a new list is created with the contents of the `IEnumerable`. (This is why the returned list is not the same as `_fakeUserList`.)

Comment: Is there any way to test it? or do I have to change the method to a `List` not an `IEnumerale`?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some additional details. It's still possible to test it, just not in the way that you're trying. :-)

Comment: This is perfect thanks for the help mate been trying to figure this out for ages!

Comment: Glad to help! And SUT ([System Under Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test "Wikipedia - System Under Test")) is just a way of referring to the thing that is the focal point of your test. In this case, it's `_userService` (or more specifically, the `AddUser` method of `UserService`).

Comment: Hi mate Just a quick question, why can't I just add `ToList()` to the `DeserialiseObject` method in my test as shown: `_jsonService.DeserializeObject<User>(_fakeUserJsonFile).ToList().Returns(_fakeUserList);`? Thanks

Comment: Short answer: because the fake list returned by `DeserializeObject` doesn't have a `Returns` method for you to use. That method is only defined for mock objects; `_jsonService` in this case. (You may want to look at this situation as a way your test is [trying to influence your design](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321503627/?tag=stackoverfl08-20 "Amazon - Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests"). Specifically, why does `GetUsers` return a `List<User>` instead of an `IEnumerable<User>`?)

Comment: I convert to a `List` because if it's an IEnumerable, it can't add a `User` to the collection. I get a `Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable`. Also explaining that IEnumerable doesn't have an `Add` method` So at some point before the `User` gets added to the collection of `Users`, it's going to have to turn it into a `List` anyway.

Comment: I'm starting to think that it might be just as easy to have both `GetUsers()` && `DeserialiseObject` as `Lists`, rather than `IEnumerables`? The reason I used `IEnumerable` for the `DeserialiseObject` method is because all it was doing was return a collection, I didn't need the extra bits that come with a `List` if that makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54640/discussion-between-lilshieste-and-paddy1990).

Comment: Ok cool didn't know we could have discussions in chat on here